# How to sort by arbitrary keywords?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        `Magic The Gathering`
    WHERE
        `set` =  'Magic 2013'
    ORDER BY
        `rarity` ASC
    LIMIT
        500
```

Rarity consists of the following keywords: Mythic, Rare, Uncommon, Common

Currently it sorts alphbetically, so it's sorted as Common, Mythic, Rare, Uncommon.

How can I sort rarity so it's displayed in the following order?

Mythic, Rare, Uncommon, Common

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this ad hoc by using the [FIELD()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_field) function in MySQL, which returns an integer, which is the position of the matching string in a list.

Example:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    `Magic The Gathering`
WHERE
    `set` =  'Magic 2013'
ORDER BY
    FIELD(`rarity`, 'Mythic', 'Rare', 'Uncommon', 'Common') ASC
LIMIT
    500
```

Note back-tick quotes are for column identifiers, whereas straight single-quotes are for string literals.

Another solution would be to define your `rarity` column as `ENUM('Mythic', 'Rare', 'Uncommon', 'Common')`, and then you could use your original query.  The sort order would be by the ordinal position of the string in the enum, not alphabetical.

Comment: Does the ENUM solution provide a faster query?

Comment: Yes, if you have a compound index over `(\`set\`, rarity)`, then the sorting is based on the index order instead of manual sorting, whereas the FIELD() solution must sort manually.

Answer (score 1):

It's as simple as that:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    `Magic The Gathering`
WHERE
    `set` =  'Magic 2013'
ORDER BY
    FIELD(`rarity`, 'Mythic', 'Rare', 'Uncoomon', 'Common') ASC
LIMIT
    500
```